# Why is my Java string being padded with nulls?

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, copy/paste from a method:

```
String harmonicFile;
...
...
harmonicFile = String.format("%04d%s",this.number, this.suffix.toUpperCase()) + ".tch";
```

The result ***looks*** OK but I have some funkiness going on:

I pass this string to another method which includes this:

```
if(filename.equals(file)){
   return file;
}
```

fileName is the value passed in and file is a match from the assets file system.  Suppose file is "0062.tch".  Inspecting filename in the Intellij IDEA debugger shows it to equal "0062.tch" yet the return statement is never hit.  On close inspection, I can see that filename is padded with 8 null chars (\u0000).

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is the string padded?
2. In IDEA, breaking on the if statement then using the expression evaluator (Alt-F8) shows filename.equals(file) to be true, but stepping through my code at runtime shows that it is not.  I assume that this is some low level difference in the way IDEA evaluates expressions and the Dalvik VM?  I assume that the VM is correct since filename does indeed NOT equal file.

Thanks for any insights.

Simon

[EDIT]  I'm convinced that the rest of the code is not relevant but here it is anyway, comments removed to save space.

```
public String filePathForHarmonicFile(){

    String harmonicFile;
    int number = this.number;

    if(this.number < 0){ return "";}

    if(number<10000 && this.suffix.length()<=1){
        harmonicFile = String.format("%04d%s",this.number, this.suffix.toUpperCase()) + ".tch";
    }else{
        harmonicFile = String.format("%s%s",this.number,this.suffix.toUpperCase()) + ".tch";
    }

    return SCFileManager.getAssetFilePath("",harmonicFile);
}

public static String getAssetFilePath(String rootOfSearch, String filename){

    try {

        // get a list of all file entries in the search root
        String[] files = ThisApplication.getContext().getAssets().list(rootOfSearch);

        for (String file:files){

            String newRoot;
            if (rootOfSearch.equals("")){
                newRoot = file;
            } else {
                newRoot = rootOfSearch + File.separator + file;
            }

            if (TidesPlannerApplication.getContext().getAssets().list(newRoot).length>0){

                String thisFile = getAssetFilePath(newRoot,filename);

                if (!thisFile.equals("")){
                    return thisFile;
                }
            } else {
                if(file.equals(filename)){
                    return file;
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }

    return "";

}
```

I know this last method is butt ugly but if someone knows a better way to deal with 7.5k files in subfolders in assets, I'm all ears - AssetManager is $%^&* brain dead!

Comment: Are both "filename" and "file" definitely both Strings?

Comment: Please try to post a complete code example, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @Simon unrelated but you can use `%S` instead of manually calling `toUpperCase` :-)

Comment: @Simon have you tried `filename.trim()`?

Comment: I tried trim.  I tried replace("\\u0000",""), I tried substring(0,7) and so on.   Actually, I'm sure I'll find a workaround but of much more interest is why is that string padded in the first place?  Especially as the last expression in the statement that builds it is +".tch";   Thanks for the %S tip.  Missed that.

Comment: what is `this.suffix` and how is it being set?

Comment: this.suffix is a field of an object in a HashMap initialised like this, structInfoReduced being the class which "this" is an instance of: gFeedData.put("60",new structInfoReduced(60,"",-14.233333,-1122.366667,"Cavre1",105,10,29,-3.000000,-1,1,0));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment you write this.

> Correct. If I inspect the backing char array, it looks like this: `[0] [0] [6] [2] [.] [t] [c] [h] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000]`

This does not necessarily mean that String is passed with NULs.

The String's state consists of the characters from `value[offset]` to `value[offset + count - 1]`.  I would surmise that `offset` must be zero, but there is no real evidence for what the value of `count` is ...

Those NULs could well be beyond the end of the String state, and hence not the cause of your problems.

Comment: That char array is the passed value, i.e. inspected in the second method and count=8!  All very odd.

Comment: @Simon - if `count` is 8, then the first NUL is beyond the end of the String.  `count + offset - 1` is `8 + 0 - 1` ... `7`

Comment: @Simon - and the most likely reason for the `value` array having the NUL's beyond the end is that the String was assembled using a StringBuilder ... which on some JVMs will transfer the ownership of its backing array to the new String when `toString()` is called.  In short, the NUL's are a total red herring.

Answer (score 1):

1) Unless I'm missing something, your string is padding because of the format statement `"%04d%s"` which will left pad with zeros to get to 4 digits, hence the "0062.tch".  Am I missing something?

For the right padding of null characters, a couple of notes.  First, each hex character is half a byte, hence (\u0000) is two bytes, hence one character.  Also, the IDEs will show you all bytes allocated in the `String`, but when its printed, compared, etc, it stops at the first null character.

Comment: I think the OP means that there are 8 unexplained trailing null chars at the end of the string.

Comment: Correct.  If I inspect the backing char array, it looks like this: [0] [0] [6] [2] [.] [t] [c] [h] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000] [\u0000]

Comment: Ah, the right padding.  I assume that's the string terminator.  You could always try some `System.out` calls.

Comment: @MartyE Java does not use NUL as a string terminator ;-)

Comment: @veer I guess it's the `String.length` that's used to determine the used parts, but the nulls to the right are not used in either case, but they are there for future use.

Comment: So why is filename.equals(file) returning false?  And the backing char array for file does NOT contain any trailing nulls.

Comment: what is the value for `filename.length` and `file.length` (assuming both are String)?

Answer (score 0):

Doh, doh, doh, doh, doh.  How is it possible to spend >3 hours looking at a problem, cry for help on SO, then spot the stupidity 5 minutes later?  Thanks for all who took time to respond and my apologies for wasting space and time.

The second method is a recursive search of the assets folder.  You can see that the result of a recursive call is stored in thisFile.  Therefore, the if statement should read:

```
if(thisFile.equals(filename)){}
```

That said, I'm still curious as to why filename is padded with nulls whereas file and thisFile are not.  However, esoteric interest only as the code now works...